# SlidingMenu ListFragment menu destroyed after OnItemClickListener fires

Tags: java, android, fragment, destructor, slidingdrawer

I'd like to start off by saying this is my first *largish* Android app...

I'm using the third-party library [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) and everything is working great except for one thing: when the user taps a list item in the "basement" menu, that ListFragment is destroyed. I set logs in all of the construction/deconstruction methods of the ListFragment to log the activity. Here's an image of the log, edited to show when the touch event occurred.

[image]

My ListFragment class is setup like so:

```java
public class BasementFragment extends ListFragment implements PictureCallback {
    BasementAdapter mAdapter;
    RelativeLayout mHeader;
    ArrayList<String> titles;
    ImageView mImageButton;

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("BASEMENTFRAGMENT", "onCreateView");
    ListView view = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.basement, null);
    mHeader = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.basement_header, null);
    view.addHeaderView(mHeader);

    mImageButton = (ImageView) mHeader.findViewById(R.id.image_button);
    mImageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pickImage();
        }
    });

    ParseFile imageFile = (ParseFile) ParseUser.getCurrentUser().get(NJUser.IMAGE_KEY);
    if (imageFile != null) {
        imageFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

            @Override
            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                mImageButton.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            }
        });
    }

    return view;
}
    // touch logic and other stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was resetting the behind views and then changing the fragments **after** setting the SlideMenu object. After I changed the order of how things were set, bam, persistence and nothing being destroyed!

Comment: I have same issue. can you clarify a bit more please.